# Azure Internal Load Balancer - Static or Dynamic?

Tags: azure

Whats the strategy for IP address when setting up ILB? It makes sense to have a static IP but when would you want Dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an internal load balancer on Azure, you will associate a virtual network and subnet with this load balancer. If you do not know which specific IP address you will use it as the frontend IP of the load balancer, you can choose Dynamic, then Azure will assign the next available unassigned or unreserved IP address in the associated subnet's address range. Also, you can change it to static after you have created your load balancer. If you want to specify a dedicated or known IP in the subnet at the first time, you could select IP address assignment static.

Read more about [Private IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#private-ip-addresses).

Comment: Thanks Nancy for your reply. So does that mean its always preferred to have static and only because we don't know what IP to associate, we assign a dynamic one? I am curious to understand how does that affect when the LB is associated to a VM scale-set?

Comment: its doesnt matter, you can always change static to dynamic and vice-versa. it works exactly the same for vmss

Comment: The Static or Dynamic IP address is just a bit difference of Allocation method, have not a preferred one. For an LB service, the frontend IP allocation method does not impact your backends, it just affects the frontends, you will access the backends via frontend IP address. If the frontend IP is static, the IP address will always the same unless deleting the associated network interface such as VM.  If the frontend IP is dynamic, for load balancer, it will always the same, will not change unless you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom-Line.

If you have an Azure environment behind a load balance you might want Frontend IP to be static so you are rest assured that you environment's public IP will not accidentally change except you want it to, especially if you are making use of SNAT.

Also you do not really save by making it dynamic, if there is a resource behind it you will have an IP charge for the whole month.